# Harmonic holomorphic function in $Ω$

Tags: holomorphic-functions

$Ω$ is simply connected in $C$,  $u$ is a harmonic function in $Ω$ , $v$ in $Ω$

$$v(x,y) = \int_0^1 (yu{\Tiny x} (sx,sy)-xu{\Tiny y} (sx,sy)) ds$$

Prove that there exists a holomorphic function $u+iv$ in $Ω$

I know the Cauchy–Riemann equations and what is the result of having a harmonic function (Im not able to write with Latex, otherwise i would write it down) 
I tried to figure out something with this, but im not coming ahead.

Comment: I tried to patch up you $\LaTeX$; hope I got it right.  Cheers!

Comment: What do you mean you've tried it in the right way? Have you tried to show that $u,v$ satisfy the Cauchy Riemann equations?

Comment: Are you familiar with the fact two Harmonic functions are conjugates if and only if they are the real and imaginary parts respectively of an analytic function?

Comment: thanks Robert Lewis :)

Comment: Alex R, it was just because i cannot write with latex, but now it stands there how it should be.

Comment: Yes Brevan Ellefsen,  I know that. But anyway i dont know what to do now.

Comment: @malilini sorry, missed your message since you didn't tag my name. At this point there are two ways you can go: use the CR equations or show $u$ and $v$ are Harmonic conjugates by a more direct method (if you know any)

Comment: @Brevan Ellefsen I tried it, but i dont really know how to go ahead.
I thought about: $$g=u{\Tiny x}- iu{\Tiny y}$$ and then I tried to use the CR equations... But no... I really don't know how to go on..